# getting error: LineChart not a constructor, and chart not displayed in web page

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, google-visualization

I have an HTML file that is supposed to display a chart which would show the details of a particular process from the past few minutes. It gives the error as follows when I declare 
`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback($scope.drawChart);`

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.LineChart is not a constructor
>       at $scope.drawChart

I am not sure how to call this function otherwise.  The following is the code in my controller JS file.

```
$scope.drawChart = function() {

    var finaldata = [[{label:'Process', type: 'string'}, {label: 'NumOfNewAssociations', type: 'number'}, {label: 'NumOfClosedAssociations', type: 'number'}, {label: 'NumOfSavedImages', type: 'number'}, {label: 'SizeOfSavedImagesInBytes', type: 'number'}]];
    for (var i = 1; i < 2/*$scope.storestats2.length*/; i++) {
        finaldata[i] = [$scope.storestats2.Process, $scope.storestats2.NumOfNewAssociations, $scope.storestats2.NumOfClosedAssociations, $scope.storestats2.NumOfSavedImages, $scope.storestats2.SizeOfSavedImagesInBytes];
    }

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(finaldata);
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Range-wise Store statistics',
            subtitle: 'in the last 30 minutes'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
};
```

I even tried including the following in the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

And this is where i intend the function to be called in my HTML:

```
<div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

I am also able to see the space being allotted in the webpage, but nothing ever shows up on it.
All other functions are working perfectly fine, except for this charts thing. I even tried doing it for just one chart. Still the same. But the code works fine when I do it as a separate HTML file, with embedded JS controller and other locally defined arrays. But I am not able to get it to work in my context where it has to be in different files.

Comment: all of those were fine WhiteHat. I figured it out somehow as to what was giving the error. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled upon a solution to this problem. But I still don't know how it solved and why.

All I had to do was make a change in just one line of the code:

I had to change:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

into

```
var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

Comment: that is due to the `'packages'` being loaded -- `google.charts.Line` is a _Material_ chart, loaded with package `'line'` -- `google.visualization.LineChart` is a _Classic_ chart, loaded with package `'corechart'` -- be aware, there are several config options that are not supported by _Material_, see [issue #: 2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks for the info @WhiteHat .